# How to make webpack generate separate CSS and JS with the same name "index" e.g. "index.js" and "index.css" when there are multiple CSS outputs?

Tags: webpack

I was able to produce separate CSS and Js as mentioned at: [Can I use webpack to generate CSS and JS separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322958/can-i-use-webpack-to-generate-css-and-js-separately/59237067#59237067)

The working baseline code below produces files named:

```
dist/index.js
dist/main.css
dist/main.js
dist/notmain.css
dist/notmain.js
```

Note that undesired `main.js` and `notmain.js` dummy files [which no ones knows how to nicely fix](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/151#issuecomment-749166647), but it doesn't matter to me in this case.

My question is, how can I get Webpack to instead generate:

```
dist/index.css
dist/index.js
dist/notmain.css
```

i.e., rename `main.css` to `index.css`?

?

Naively, what I wanted would be to just modify the working baseline to:

```
  entry: {
    index: ['./index.js'],
    index: ['./index.scss'],
  },
```

but then that wouldn't make any sense, since the `entry` dict now has two `index` keys, and the second one would erase the first.

Also, if I had just a single CSS output, I could just hardcode:

```
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'index.css',
    }),
```

but since I have multiple ones, that won't cut it, I need that `[name]` placeholder to work somehow.

I've seen at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#output-filename that it documents that something like:

```
    main: {
      import: './main.scss',
      filename: 'index.css',
    },
```

could work, but if I try that it fails with:

```
ERROR in index.css
index.css from Css Minimizer
/home/ciro/bak/git/cirosantilli.github.io/webpack/tmp/index.css:1:10: Unknown word [index.css:1,10]
```

A similar question about this error message can be seen at: [webpack fails "module build failed: unknown word" with webpack.config.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261548/webpack-fails-module-build-failed-unknown-word-with-webpack-config-js-file) What happens is that for some reason `dist/index.css` contains a JavaScript file, and the then CSS minifier fails to parse it. An analogous change for `index.js` did work for JavaScript though, it's something specific to this CSS setup.

**Working baseline code**

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Sass import</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/notmain.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
<script src="dist/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += '<p>js works</p>'
```

main.scss

```
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

notmain.scss

```
body {
  color: blue;
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const nodeModulesPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    index: ['./index.js'],
    main: ['./main.scss'],
    notmain: ['./notmain.scss'],
  },
  mode: 'none',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
    minimize: true,
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-cheat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "sass": "rm -f dist/main.css && sass -I node_modules main.scss dist/main.css"
  },
  "author": "Ciro Santilli",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "5.2.4",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "normalize.css": "8.0.1",
    "sass": "1.32.11",
    "sass-loader": "11.0.1",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "webpack": "5.36.1",
    "webpack-cli": "4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Compile and run:

```
npm install
npm run build
xdg-open index.html
```

Also asking at: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/15163

Answer (score 0):

The amazing Webpack developer Alexander Akait [just replied to me](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/15163#discussioncomment-1983959) with a working workaround:

```
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: (pathData) => {
        if (pathData.chunk.name === "main") {
          return 'index.css'
        }

        return '[name].css'
      },
    }),
  ],
```

so we see that `filename` can take an arbitrary function and not just strings, and then we are able to fix things up with that greater flexibility.

He also mentions:

> I see, yep, it is limitation, we are working on built-in CSS support (it will resolve the problem), currently please use:

so it appears that Webpack as historically been more focused on the "inject CSS with Js approach", but that this is now being generalized.

Thanks Alexander!

Answer (score 0):

You want something similar to this, here are some excerpts from my own config, using webpack v5:

```js
module.exports = {
 // other stuff omitted
 output: {
    // other stuff omitted
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js'
  },
  entry: {
    index: [
      './src/index.js'
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      ignoreOrder: true
    }),
  ]
}
```

the `[name]` substituion can be used to map back to the name on disk.

see

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#output-filenames
- https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputdevtoolmodulefilenametemplate

for more information

Comment: Hi, can this code really produce a CSS and Js with the same filename e.g. `dist/index.js` and `dist/index.css`? How is it different from my code?

Comment: I am not certain, I have never used CSS as an entry point, what filenames do you get with your current setup?

Comment: dist/index.js dist/main.css dist/notmain.css and the undesired but harmless dist/main.js
and dist/notmain.js

Comment: BTW, Webpack developer Alexander Akait gave a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70698776/895245