# How to fix 'Unknown word' error when bundling css file in webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, tailwind-css, monaco-editor

I am building an Electron app in Angular and I am upgrading a couple of dependencies to the latest versions.

- ✅ Electron stays on `v19`
- ✅ Tailwindcss `v3.1.8`
- ⬆️ Angular `v11` to `v14`
- ⬆️ Webpack `v4.46.0` to `v5.74.0`

ℹ️ The entire project compiled before successfully.

I am using the [monaco-editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor) and since bumping the deps above I am running into an issue during the bundling stage of webpack.

```js
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError

(2:7) /.../projects/foo/node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css Unknown word

  1 | 
> 2 |       import API from "!../../../../style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
    |       ^
  3 |       import domAPI from "!../../../../style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";
  4 |       import insertFn from "!../../../../style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";
```

Before bumping the versions the `webpack.config.json` only contained a rule for `/\.scss$/`! But suddenly with webpack v5 it failed that it is unable to understand some `css` files (famous error: `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type`).

So I assumed a rule for CSS was missing. I added the rule and my webpack file now looks like this:

```json
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader"
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'postcss-loader',
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: sassImplementation,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Please note the order `"style-loader"`, `"css-loader"`, `'postcss-loader'` that has been reported as the correct one in posts like [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/295#issuecomment-297817628) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261548/webpack-fails-module-build-failed-unknown-word-with-webpack-config-js-file). I still receive the error above.

Can anyone point out if my webpack is misconfigured or if I missed a rule?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I had an application working 3 days ago and now, without any change, it's not working anymore...

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. If you also are stuck in this, maybe a dependency bump somewhere?

Comment: Yeah that was my thought, probably a minor webpack or css plugins version (app was created pretty recently)

Comment: I solved doing this  `{ test: /\.css$/, use: [ { loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' } ], exclude: /node_modules/ }` but i'm not sure it applies to your case because the css that was giving me issues was inside node_modules so ignoring it solved my problem

Comment: I have the same, my `css` is located inside `node_modules`. Does that mean by ignoring it it will simply not be part of the bundle and stay a separate resource?

Comment: I haven't gotten as far as deplyoing the application but i've just tried to build the application and it put the css from my node_modules into the bundle. I invite you to test this solution and see if it works for you too

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine the tests? No need to have two different since the Sass loader will convert it to CSS.

```
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader"
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              implementation: sassImplementation,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it with `/\.s?css$/` to cover `.css` as well as `.scss` and all loaders as in your example, but unfortunately the error stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 { 
   test: /\.scss$/,
      //install these npm packages and use it in this exact order to compile scss files
        use: [
               'style-loader',
               'css-loader', 
               'sass-loader'
             ],
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.